# Where is the centripetal force acting on mass $M$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

Look at the image below where I've drawn a rigid triangle, with thin lightweight rods and a fixed mass $M$ attached as shown. There is a torque applied at a fixed pivot point $P$ bisecting the top rod. Let's assume $M$ is at rest and then a torque is added about pivot point $P$.

Am I correct that forces $F_1$ and $F_2$ will act on mass M, with a resultant net tangential force direction as shown?

So mass M will move in a circular path but where is the centripetal force to keep it moving it in a circle?

[image]

Comment: Is M initially at rest or is it already rotating?

Comment: Without forces M would move in a straight line at constant velocity. If it moves in a circle at constant speed, the total force must be toward the center and the magnitude must be $m\omega^2r$. The rods must supply this force.

Comment: How do you know that the two force have the same magntude?

Comment: Let's assume M is at rest and then a torque is added about pivot point P.  If I added those forces F applied to the mass M , there is no centripetal force , just a tangential force. But if the M moves in a circle , there must be a centripetal force.  I'll add another diagram with my assumption of the forces along the rods being equal (maybe others can then identify where I may be going wrong).

Comment: nasu :  I've drawn a couple force F as shown in my edited diagram . So aren't the forces F1 and F2 the same?

Comment: There is no reason to be equal. Do you have a reason for it? Only if the body is at rest, hanging from the two bars, you my have a reason to suppose that they are equal.

Comment: nasu :  The torque forces F applied as shown in the image won't change , so why should the forces in the arms change? I cannot see how the forces in the arms will change as it angularly accelerates. Is there a simple way of explaining how these forces could create a centripetal force? The left arm is being pushed , while the right arm is being pulled , so I can only imagine that the force in the right arm will get larger than the left (but how?).

Answer (score 1):

Since $M$ is at rest initially the centripetal acceleration is initially $$a_c=\frac{v^2}{r}=0$$

So your analysis is correct. The initial acceleration is purely tangential and there is no centripetal force initially because there is no centripetal acceleration when $M$ is at rest.

Later on, as $M$ gains velocity the forces in the members will no longer be equal in magnitude. There will be a component of tangential force as well as a component of centripetal force.

Comment: Many thanks Dale. Do you know of any previous answer that provides more detail as to how the forces in the rods change as angular velocity increases? Or can you point me to a link where I can learn more?

Comment: @Dubious I don’t have a link for you. But once you have the tangential force and centripetal force then you can just write two equations in two unknowns to get F1 and F2